# What is the closest equivalent in Netbeans to Eclipse's Templates (code macros)?

Tags: eclipse, templates, netbeans, macros

In Eclipse, I can define a **template** like this:

[image]

so that when I'm typing I type the **first letters** of the template name, choose the template:

[image]

and it pops in the code with **variables**:

[image]

**What is the best way to get this functionality in NetBeans?**

Answer (score 0):

Code templates.

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/code-templates.html

Link goes to a PHP-specific tutorial, but it's the same for any language that your Netbeans build has support for.